# Is it still possible to send an email/text using SMTP?

Tags: vb.net, email, text, smtp

I have a program I have setup for a home automation application.  My goal is to get it to text me if there's a critical error but I'm having issues with the smtp portion.  I am able to get my app to work just fine using my company's SMTP (basically, I wanted to start with a working, closed system before I tried moving to free options, as those are more restrictive, ironically enough).

I've run through many, many examples online and it appears to be an issue with the SMTP's blocking certain methods/ports.  I've tried the below code with ports 25, 465, and 587 (the common ports that are used online).  I've also tried changing the EnableSs1 to false but that hasn't worked either.

I know I can probably pay for an SMTP server but I'm trying to do it on the cheap (read: free) first.  Realistically, I'm not anticipating needing many notifications.  I had found turboSMTP, which is free but I have to not be using a free email address and they verify your home address (which sounds a bit shady . . .).

Anyway, my code is below.  If there's any way to get this working (or if you know of a free, usable SMTP or even another method for doing this), please let me know!

I am more than willing to do the work myself, I'm not just trying to get a solution from someone else but I'm kinda at the end of what I know how to do.  Any help you can give me would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Try
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Smtp_Server.Port = 465
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("From Email Address", "From Email Name")
        e_mail.To.Add("My Phone Number@mms.att.net")

        e_mail.Subject = "Hello there!"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text

        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: And what is the error message received by this code? Anything related to invalid credentials?

Comment: Oh, it's a pretty long winded response with port 25 or 587 (Failure sending email, unable to connect to remove server, attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by it's access permissions, etc).  Sounds like these ports are just flat out being blocked from being used in this way.  Port 465 just appears to timeout though.

Comment: You indicate that all you want is a free service.  FWIW, I tested your code with the addition of a NetworkCredential on AOL and it works fine.  Just use port 587 and Enablessl=True per their setup instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
...
Try
        Dim Email As New MailMessage()
        Email.From = New MailAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com")
        Email.To.Add("other@provider.com")
        Email.Subject = "TEST GMAIL"
        Email.IsBodyHtml = False
        Email.Body = TextBox1.Text

        Dim EmailClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        EmailClient.EnableSsl = True
        EmailClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "password")
        EmailClient.Timeout = 7000
        EmailClient.Send(Email)

Catch ex As SmtpException
        MsgBox(ex.StatusCode & vbCrLf & ex.Message, vbCritical, "SMTP Error!")
End Try
```

Strange. Google Help suggests using port 465 - not working, timeout. Sending mail on port 587.
EnableSsl must be set to True. In credentials, username must be full e-mail address.

Tested on VB2010 with no errors. E-mail delivered immediately.

**UPDATE**: added timeout in miliseconds and modify catch to SmtpException.
Target framework: .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Comment: I am guessing it will work in accounts which does not have 2-step-auth or business accounts (like the ones I own)... Didn't you get security exceptions?

Comment: Hmm... i have normal account without 2-step-auth... Sending fast with no errors, no problems...

Comment: Hmm.  That's really odd.  I pasted your code directly into my application (with the authentications updated) and it doesn't seem to work (I get "Failure to send").  I guess that probably means either the ports are being blocked here at work (IT tells me that's not the case), it's being blocked on the email recipient end (in my case, both @mms.att.net and @hotmail.com), or it could be VB2012 related?  I have VB2010 express on my computer, I'll try it there as well.  I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Well, I tried it in 2010.  Still not working. I'm kind of at a loss to know why it is it's working on your end but not on mine.  What provider are you sending it to, out of curiosity?  Does the above code work if you tried to send it to a gmail address?

Comment: Hmm... i have VB2010Ex & .NET 4 Client Profile. Sending mails from gmail, to gmail, and from-to gmail. Fast and no errors. Try modify code in catch block to get status code and message from smtp. I have no idea why your code not working...

Comment: @J B, ask IT at your job if your workstation is blocking these ports to send e-mail, with a software firewall. The IT are correct that they aren't blocking them in the DMZ, but some companies also use workstation software firewalls to block things.